# How to Show Single Column Value in Multiple Columns with Splitting

Tags: mysql, h2

I have a table `flats` with single column `flat_no` with values like

```
table flats

flat_no
101
102
103
104
105
  .
  .
  . so on
200
```

in the above table i have flat_no 101 to 200, so here i just want to split the `flat_no` column values in 2 parts and display them in 2 columns.

I need expected output something like

```
 c1       c2   
101      151
102      152
103      153 
.          .
.          .
. so on    . so on
150      200
```

I have written a query to achieve this scenario but unable to get the exact output

```
select rownum, (case when rownum<=50 then flat_no else 0 end) c1, 
    (case when rownum >50 then flat_no else 0 end) c2 from flats
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually something like this is done with self join like so:

```
select * from flats f1 join flats f2 on f1.flat_no + 50 = f2.flat_no;
```

In your case you can just add 50 to the same column without doing join:

```
select flat_no, flat_no + 50 from flats where flat_no <= 150;
```